# Where did the button to hang up the phone from the lock screen go on iOS 10

Tags: iphone, ios

Since upgrading to iOS 10 I've noticed that often when I want to hang up a call, I now have to unlock the phone, navigate to the phone app to finally press the red "hang up" button.

Previously there would be some basic phone controls like "Mute" and "Hang up" even if the phone decided to lock while you were on the call.  Now all I see is the contact information and call duration where the clock would be and "Press home to unlock" on the bottom.  No phone controls.

How can I reenable the phone controls on the lock screen?

Comment: This is a bug actually, it should work the way you're used to.  I have experienced the same thing.  I recommend backing up the iPhone, doing a full wipe on it and restoring from the backup to see if that clears it up.

Comment: This is so obnoxious.  I cannot figure out how to get back to the phone "app" while the phone is locked at the end of a call.  Several times I've ended up in the camera, taking photos of the floor trying to get the phone to click home to unlock.  I feel like my grandmother trying to use an iPhone.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

On the lock screen in iOS 10, a swipe right gets you to that new lock info screen (this used to get you call controls), a swipe left gets you the camera.  I had the same reaction, how do I get to call controls?!?

It turns out, you just need to **tap** the phone number or contact name displayed on the lock screen, and you will get the call controls.  This makes sense, in hindsight, as the swipe right now has a new behavior, but it wasn't obvious to me either.

Also, the sleep/wake physical button hands up the phone, so that's often easier than using the screen in many situations.

Comment: Tested this now.  Waited for the phone to lock while on a call.  Tapping the call information brings up the familiar call control screen without unlocking required.  Success!  You are a hero Brian!  I would never have discovered this normally.

Comment: Perfect, just tab the call information.... made my day

Comment: Why this simple action must be so unobvious??? What a poor UX from Apple

Comment: So that's still 3 actions which, in my opinion, is pretty shoddy UX for something so primitive. Route 1: Lock button -> Tap phone number or contact -> hangup. Route 2 (assumes touch id): Home button -> call app -> hangup.

Comment: Thank you for the info on clicking the contact info! Hat helps greatly, especially for the case where you'd switched to a different app before locking. Even if you hadn't, though, and even with touch id, unlocking seems much slower than this option, so thanks! I'm wondering, though: sleep/wake/power button hangs up for you?? It doesn't seem to for me. Is there some setting somewhere I need to set? (I couldn't find one, where I looked.)

Answer (score 4):

As long as you are not on speakerphone, you can always end the call using the power button. Just press it once.

By the way, this feature exists since 2007 when Steve Jobs revealed the original iPhone.

Comment: This explains why the phone hung up every time I tried to take a screen shot to attach.  Solves the "Hang up" issue, but still no access to the "mute" , "Dialled" or "Speaker" buttons if they are not displayed.  That said, this answers the "How do I hang up when wearing gloves in the winter" question.

Comment: This seems to only work under two conditions: 1. You're not currently on headphones or speakerphone, and 2: the phone is not in proximity mode. Even then, it seems like it doesn't always work, at least for me. :(

Comment: @lindes The fact that it *depends on context* is absolutely awful. "Why am I quiet? Well, I'm thinking about which voicecall state my phone is currently in and which behavior the power button has in that state so that I don't accidentally hang up on you"

Answer (score -1):

This is definitely a bug. Tapping on home button does not work for me as it pulls up unlock code screen - I need this feature still so that family members can use my phone. My hands are too small to reach the top of the screen while operating the phone with one hand (i.e while driving). I have never been so frustrated with iOS, nor felt so unsafe while driving.

Comment: I agree looking at the phone while driving is unsafe. Consider using handsfree or using the sleep/wake button to hang up if you must use a hand while driving.